# Can you enable AVX intrinsics when using Meson?

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, meson-build

I’m building a C++ project and want to make use of AVX intrinsics. I’m sure my CPU supports them as I have written a test project and compiled it manually with `clang -mavx`. But I don’t know how to enable it under Meson. I have tried adding `c_args : ['-mavx']` and `link_args : ['-mavx']` but I still get the following errors from the compiler:

```
error: AVX vector argument of type '__m256' (vector of 8 'float' values) without 'avx' enabled changes the ABI
error: AVX vector return of type '__m256' (vector of 8 'float' values) without 'avx' enabled changes the ABI
```

How can I enable the flag `-mavx` under Meson?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `cpp_args : ['-mavx']`